# Determining the TFS server

Tags: c#, tfs

I am attempting to create an application that requires a TFS server URL.

The only way I can find is to open a .sln file that is under source control and look at the "SccTeamFoundationServer" attribute. I'm sure there must be a way to get the server from Visual Studio, but I'm not sure how to do that in c#.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put the TFS server's URL in your app's config?

Comment: Putting the URL in the app.config was my solution as well

Comment: There may be more than one TFS Server configured in Visual Studio. What kind of code are you writing? A VS addin? or some external program?

Comment: @Simon Woops, I should have mentioned that earlier. I am working on a VS addin.

Comment: I think the way to go is VersionControlExplorerItem.SourceServerPath and this 2005 blog post shows how to use it.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2006/02/03/524312.aspx.  theres a few bits on using it with 2010 which looks promising

Comment: @Mike That looks incredibly promising, thank you.

On a side note, is it possible for me to mark this comment as an answer, or what should I do to close this question?

Comment: sorry cant edit the above post - for reference fix see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/1f6a95cc-ad1e-4866-9b3c-3327595e3e1c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from comments in Question.

I think the way to go is VersionControlExplorerItem.SourceServerPath and this 2005 blog post shows how to use it. blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2006/02/03/524312.aspx. theres a few bits on using it with 2010 which looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a c# program, I think you are doing the correct way, there is no other.